# Webclient DownloadFile with ClientCertificate

Tags: c#, certificate, webclient

I'm trying to download a pfx file on an url. On chrome when I open the link, I had to select a certificate and then to log on. But when I try it with C# WebClient I got an error 403 "Forbidden".

How can I specifies a certificate or bypass this step programmatically ?

My code :

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MyLogin, MyPassword);
    client.DownloadFile(MyUrl, MyFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get a solution: overriding WebClient !

New webClient :

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate;

    public MyWebClient(X509Certificate2 certificate)
        : base()
    {
        this.certificate = certificate;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        request.Credentials = this.Credentials;
        return request;
    }
}
```

The way to use it :

```
using (var client = new MyWebClient(MyCertificate))
{
    // optional login/password if website require both. If not, don't set the credentials
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MyLogin, MyPassword);
    client.DownloadFile(MyUrl, MyFile);
}
```

Comment: @MercuryX hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone stumbles on this question and answer, implementation of WebClient override should be just a bit different.

```
public class ExtendedWebClient : System.Net.WebClient
{
    X509Certificate2 _certificate;

    public ExtendedWebClient() : base() { }

    public ExtendedWebClient(X509Certificate2 certificate) : base()
    {
        _certificate = certificate;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        // Base method creates HttpWebRequest and sets other needed stuff like POST method or authentication/authorization headers.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.Create(address);
        if(_certificate!=null && address.Schema=="https")
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(_certificate);            
        return request;
    }
}
```

and then use it either as the original is used or with Client Certificate when requesting over "htttps" as

```
// For download
using(var client = new ExtendedWebClient(MyCertificate))
{
    // Add anything optional like authnetication or header here.
    client.DownloadFile(MyUrl, MyFile);
}

// ...

// Or for upload
using(var client = new ExtendedWebClient(MyCertificate))
{
    // Add anything optional like authnetication or header here.
    client.UploadFile(MyUrl, "POST", MyFile);
}
```